# Is there a way to pass a parameter to a predicate in JavaScript using ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a functional code in JavaScript with ramda library. I would like to have a generic function `hasNChars` and dynamically pass the parameter `n`. I cannot do `R.any(hasNChars(10), words)` because the function is evaluated.

So is there a way to pass a value for the n parameter somehow?

```
var R = require('ramda');

let words = ['forest', 'gum', 'pencil', 'wonderful', 'grace',
    'table', 'lamp', 'biblical', 'midnight', 'perseverance', 
    'adminition', 'redemption'];

let hasNChars = (word, n=3) => word.length === n;

let res = R.any(hasNChars, words);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, you just need to create another function that takes N that you can immediately evaluate without needing to input `word` too, this way the N value is in scope for the final evaluation.

`let hasNChars = (n=3) => (word) => word.length === n;`

Usage: 
`let res = R.any(hasNChars(10), words);`

Usage with default n=3: 
`let res = R.any(hasNChars(), words);`

Comment: If you're willing to loose the default `n` value, you can use Ramda's `curry` function: `let hasNChars = R.curry((n, word) => word.length === n)` You can then write both `hasNChars(3)("word")` or `hasNChars(3, "word")`

Comment: Good suggestion, I've also modified my answer to include how you would currently use the default in my approach.

Comment: The syntax `(n=3) => (word) => {}` creates two functions? Is there a name perhaps for it?

Comment: @JanBodnar it creates one function that returns a function, it's a bit hard to read at first, but you'll get used to it. Splitting function arguments into multiple functions with one argument is commonly called currying. And writing functions that can return functions is part of the essence of functionnal programming

Comment: @user3297291: Your comment would make a very good alternative answer.  It's certainly how I see Ramda generally used.